# How to pass static constant as parameter in Spring config?

Tags: java, spring

This is my class:

```
public class MyClassA {

    private int mode;
    public static int THREAD_MODE=1;
    public static int CLUSTER_MODE=2;

    public MyClassA(int mode) {
         this.mode= mode;
    }
}
```

and I want to send this information in my spring configuration xml to my class instance. How do I achieve something like this?

```
<bean id="myclass" class="com.test.MyClassA"> <constructor-arg value="MyClassA.THREAD_MODE"/> </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would perhaps use enums instead of ints (more type-safe and limited in their range). Spring will support injection of enums. See [this article](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?112691-Enum-injection-via-spring) for more info.

Comment: Enums kind of seem to be an overkill, for two modes?

Comment: I disagree. They're strongly typed and you can't (easily) provide an invalid value. e.g. in the OP you could mistakenly enter '3'. Imagine(also) that you have multiple args. It's easy to confuse the order of parameters. If those args are ints, then the compiler won't help you. If they're distinct enums then the compiler will object

Comment: @Jay: No, I also think an enum would be a better fit here. Besides type-safety and proper range limits, any state or behavior bound to a particular mode can be encapsulated in the enum constant, so you can do stuff like `mode.getSomething()` instead of case-switching the int value everywhere you need some information.

Comment: alright marked this as answer, although I am not happy with creating so many classes :-)

Comment: `public static int THREAD_MODE=1; public static int CLUSTER_MODE=2;`  versus `public enum Mode {THREAD, CLUSTER}` - enums definitely aren't overkill :-)

Comment: Its not that I am not all for enums - its just that, its nice when enums carry some properties/functionality that they make more sense, rather than just being substitutes for constants.

Comment: The linked article no longer resolves and goes to the following page:  https://spring.io/blog/2019/02/06/legacy-forums-will-be-shutdown-february-28

Answer (score 15):

The `util` namespace provides a `constant` element that does exactly this:

```
<constructor-arg>
    <util:constant static-field="MyClassA.THREAD_MODE"/>
</constructor-arg>
```

The support for this functionality is provided by the `FieldRetrievingFactoryBean` class.

This requires adding a namespace and some schemas to your `<beans>` element, namely, the items below mentioning `util`.

```xml
<beans xmlns="..."
    xmlns:xyz="..."
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="...
    ...
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

Comment: having trouble specifying this in the xml. Is it valid for older versions of spring?

Comment: No, not really. I updated the answer to point out the actual underlying mechanism. You can use the `FieldRetrievingFactoryBean` directly if you're not able to make use of the `util:` namespace.